# can't remove optional() from string after updating to latest xcode?

Tags: swift2, optional-values

after updating xcode I simply can't remove the optional() from my string?

```
retrievedUsername = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("username")!
```

this prints out

> optional("HK")

but I need it to be

> HK

I've tried

```
if let username = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("username"){
   retrievedUsername = username
}
```

but no luck!
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value is probably an optional containing an optional, so you'll have to unwrap it twice:

```
if let temp = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("username"), let username = temp {
    retrievedUsername = username
}
```

If this doesn't work, this is because it's not a double optional, and it means that your original string already contains the *text* "Optional(HK)" due to a prior error.

Comment: "initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'" it fails to build, @Eric.

Comment: Then it's not a double optional, and it probably means that your original string already contains the *text* "Optional(HK)" due to a prior error. You should check what is actually stored in KeychainWrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, it would save to the keychain with "optional" so when it retrieves the string it is "optional("HK")" that's why unwrapping it didn't work